# Getting norm of a big sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, norm

I have a very big 500,000 X 500,000 but sparse matrix. I want to find its norm using Python, I tried using:

```py
%timeit numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
```

where `a` is the matrix

I also tried this:

```py
b = numpy.asarray(a, numpy.float32)
numpy.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)
```

But the Google Colabalways crashes.

I also tried doing this:

```py
import numpy as np
a =  np.random.rand(1000000,100)
print(np.linalg.norm(a, axis =1).shape)

def g(d, out=None):
    bs = 2000
    if out is None:
        r = np.empty(d.shape[0])
    else:
        r = out
    for i in range(0, d.shape[0], bs):
        u = min(i + bs, d.shape[0])
        r[i:u] = np.linalg.norm(d[i:u], axis=1)
    return r


print((g(a) == numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)).all())
print("blocked")
%timeit -n 10 g(a)
print("normal")
%timeit -n 10 numpy.linalg.norm(a, axis =1)
```

from one of the previous stack overflow questions, but still the kernel crashes, Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Did you look for a sparse norm?   `scipy.sparse.linalg.norm`

Comment: Yes I did, but the issue is with the size of the matrix, the kernel always dies and has to restart.  The matrix is 500k x 500k . Is there some memory requirement, like currently I am using Colab which gives 12 GB of RAM. Will using a 16GB or 32GB will help?

Comment: Is your matrix actually sparse? You generate a dense 1 million by 100 matrix in your example.

Comment: The kernel death is probably caused by a memory error.  Running this code as a plain python script might tell you where the error occurs - if it's in a python/numpy step as opposed to a compiled function.  You talk about sparse, but I don't see evidence of using `scipy.sparse` code to create the matrix.  I don't like testing memory error examples; but will test smaller cases to get a sense of the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

If I make a modest sized sparse matrix:

```
In [109]: M = sparse.random(10,100,.2, 'csr'); M
Out[109]: 
<10x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I can't use `np.linalg.norm` on it:

```
In [110]: np.linalg.norm(M,axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[110], line 1
----> 1 np.linalg.norm(M,axis=1)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in norm(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:2542, in norm(x, ord, axis, keepdims)
   2539 elif ord is None or ord == 2:
   2540     # special case for speedup
   2541     s = (x.conj() * x).real
-> 2542     return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
   2543 # None of the str-type keywords for ord ('fro', 'nuc')
   2544 # are valid for vectors
   2545 elif isinstance(ord, str):

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

But I can do it on its dense equivalent.  `M.A` will produce a memory error is `M` dimensions are large.

```
In [111]: np.linalg.norm(M.A,axis=1)
Out[111]: 
array([2.08644827, 2.61130439, 2.69501798, 2.33149559, 2.53580021,
       3.35499087, 2.14149997, 1.45864564, 2.56890956, 2.76315379])
```

`sparse` has a norm that works on `M`:

```
In [112]: sparse.linalg.norm(M,axis=1)
Out[112]: 
array([2.08644827, 2.61130439, 2.69501798, 2.33149559, 2.53580021,
       3.35499087, 2.14149997, 1.45864564, 2.56890956, 2.76315379])
```

For this `L2` norm I can do the sparse calculation directly:

```
In [113]: M.power(2).sum(axis=1)
Out[113]: 
matrix([[ 4.35326638],
        [ 6.81891059],
        [ 7.2631219 ],
        [ 5.43587169],
        [ 6.43028271],
        [11.25596371],
        [ 4.58602212],
        [ 2.1276471 ],
        [ 6.59929632],
        [ 7.63501886]])
```

This sum produces a (1,10) dense matrix.  Using `A1` to make a 1d array, I get the same numbers:

```
In [114]: M.power(2).sum(axis=1).A1**.5
Out[114]: 
array([2.08644827, 2.61130439, 2.69501798, 2.33149559, 2.53580021,
       3.35499087, 2.14149997, 1.45864564, 2.56890956, 2.76315379])
```

However it's done we need a tempory array/matrix that's just as large to hold the square values.  The sum reduces the dimension etc.

### sparse array

I don't need the `A1` step if I make a `sparse_array` (which `sparse` is moving towards slowly).

```
In [115]: M = sparse.random(10,100,.2, 'csr'); M = sparse.csr_array(M);M
Out[115]: 
<10x100 sparse array of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [116]: sparse.linalg.norm(M,axis=1)
Out[116]: 
array([2.21844541, 2.3164772 , 2.56784187, 2.69002853, 2.57405933,
       3.44123739, 2.41489642, 1.87393488, 2.08952551, 2.93634053])

In [117]: M.power(2).sum(1)
Out[117]: 
array([ 4.92150002,  5.36606664,  6.59381185,  7.23625348,  6.62578144,
       11.84211477,  5.83172473,  3.51163195,  4.36611684,  8.62209571])
```